# Which lens hood should I use for EF-S 18-55mm III kit lens?

Tags: lens, canon, photography-basics, lens-hood, ef-s

I've just bought a Canon EOS 4000D which shipped with a EF-S 18-55m 1:3.5-5.6 III kit lens.

Which lens hood should I purchase that is compatible with this lens?

Any resources on how to know which lens hood is compatible for which lens would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Canon EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 III is low cost kit lens without Image stabilization. It is based on the older EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS II and uses the same **EW-60C lens hood**.   It is not a very well known lens and even Canon websites don't have much information about the correct lens hood for it. The best info source may be Wikipedia: [Canon EF-S 18-55mm lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF-S_18%E2%80%9355mm_lens)

Some unscrupulous third party, (non-Canon) manufacturers sell a EW-60C “petal” or “flower” shaped lens hood. Because this lens has a front section that rotates as you focus,  it will cause the “petal” hood to be visible in the photo at 18mm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Canon EW-63C Lens Hood for EF-S 18-55mm (Canon part #8268B001). Or you can get an after market one on Amazon for cheap.

Comment: Forgot to add just google your lens tons of info plus Accessories

Comment: This answer is incorrect for the question asked. The EW-63C ONLY fits the STM versions of the 18-55. The original question is about the EF-S 18-55m 1:3.5-5.6 III. Please edit or delete this answer.